# How to change button color on mouse hover and override default behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am working on a C# forms application. i want to set custom color for the buttons when mouse is over them

By default what happens is, when mouse moves over a button its color changes slightly.

I changed the color using the onmouseover function. the issue i am having is the when i move the cursor over the button the button color changes to the default mouse over color for a split second and then it changes to the color i have set.
so what is happening is when i move the mouse over the button changes color twice. I want it to change directly to the color i have set for the button

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Simply go for the Appearance.FlatStyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Windows forms Control.MouseHover event. There's an intentional delay on this event. If you want your color change to trigger immediately try using Control.MouseEnter event, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter?view=net-5.0